# How to join two tables without repeating the same rows for different values in table

Tags: sql, db2

### First table:

```
+ ---+-----------+
| id | country   |
+ ---+-----------+
| 1  | India     |
| 2  | Australia |
| 3  | Canada    |
| 4  | France    |
| 5  | Russia    |
+ ---+-----------+
```

### Second table:

```
+ ---+-------+------------+
| id | user  | country_id |
+ ---+-------+------------+
| 1  | Ojas  | 1          |
| 2  | Raj   | 1          |
| 3  | John  | 3          |
| 4  | Robin | 2          |
| 5  | Mary  | 5          |
| 6  | Kamal | 4          |
| 7  | Bipin | 5          |
| 8  | Rohit | 1          |
+ ---+-------+------------+
```

### Expected result:

```
+ -----------+---------------+-------+
| country_id | country       | user  |
+ -----------+---------------+-------+
| 1          | India         | Ojas  |
| null       | null          | Raj   |
| null       | null          | Rohit |
| 2          | Australia     | Robin |
| 3          | Canada        | John  |
| 4          | France        | Kamal |
| 5          | Russia        | Mary  |
| null       | null          | Bipin |
+ -----------+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: I have removed all those conflicting dbms tags. Can you put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: This is something I'd do in an above, presentation, layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use aggregation methods of mysql and PostgreSql GROUP_CONCAT and string_agg(some_column, ',') methods respectively to join names with comma and get 1 record for each country as a result.

> For Mysql

```
SELECT countries.id AS Id, countries.name AS Country, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT users.name) as Users
FROM countries
INNER JOIN users ON users.country_id = countries.id
GROUP BY countries.id;
```

> For PostgreSql

```
SELECT countries.id AS Id, countries.name AS Country, string_agg(users.name, ',') as Users
FROM countries
INNER JOIN users ON users.country_id = countries.id
GROUP BY countries.id;
```

It will produce result like

```
Id | Country     | User
---------------------------------
1  | India       | Ojas,Raj,Rohit
2  | Australia   | Robin
3  | Canada      | John
4  | France      | Kamal
5  | Russia      | Mary,Bipin
---------------------------------
```

Comment: A good idea. That would actually be my preferred way to do this in SQL. If separate rows are desired as shown in the request, I'd rather care about this layout in my app or Website, not in SQL.

Comment: Thanks, I used LISTAGG in DB2

Answer (score 1):

Use `LAG` to see whether the previous row contains the same country.

```
select
  case when lag(c.id) over (order by c.id, u.user) = c.id then null else c.id end
    as country_id,
  case when lag(c.id) over (order by c.id, u.user) = c.id then null else c.country end
    as country,
  u.user
from countries c
join users u on u.country_id = c.id
order by c.id, u.user;
```

`LAG` is standard SQL and accordingly available in many DBMS (Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL as of version 8, ...).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server`, you can try like following.

```
SELECT c.id AS country_id, 
       c.country, 
       t.[user] 
FROM   (SELECT s.country_id, 
               s.[user], 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY s.country_id 
                   ORDER BY s.id) rn 
        FROM   @second s) t 
       LEFT JOIN @country c 
              ON t.country_id = c.id 
                 AND t.rn = 1
```

**[Online Demo](https://rextester.com/ZYDI72034)**

**Output**

```
+------------+-----------+-------+
| country_id | country   | user  |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| 1          | India     | Ojas  |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| NULL       | NULL      | Raj   |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| NULL       | NULL      | Rohit |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2          | Australia | Robin |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| 3          | Canada    | John  |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| 4          | France    | Kamal |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| 5          | Russia    | Mary  |
+------------+-----------+-------+
| NULL       | NULL      | Bipin |
+------------+-----------+-------+
```

**For Other Databases :**

Same query can be written without `ROW_NUMBER()` like following, so that it will work on other databases like `mysql`.

```
SELECT c.id AS country_id, 
       c.country, 
       t.user 
FROM   (SELECT s.country_id, 
               s.user, 
               s.id,
               CASE 
                 WHEN (SELECT Min(id) 
                       FROM   second s2 
                       WHERE  s2.country_id = s.country_id) = s.id THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
               END rn 
        FROM   second s) t 
       LEFT JOIN country c 
              ON t.country_id = c.id 
                 AND t.rn = 1 
ORDER  BY t.country_id ,t.id
```

[**MySQL db-fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wEH5hNRZduU4qcjebym4H7/1)